# Markov Chain $3$-step state $X_3 \mid X_0=1$ conditional probabilities, mean and variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the Markov chain with one-step transition probability matrix:
$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 &1/3  &1/3 \\ 
3/4 &1/8  &1/8\\ 
1/4 &1/2  &1/4
\end{bmatrix}$$ and initial probabilities $p_{0} = p_{1} = p_{2} = 1/3.$

1. Compute the three-step transition probability matrix.
2. Find $ P (X_{0} = 1, X_{3} = 0).$
3. Find $P (X_{3} = 0).$
4. Find $P (X_{0}= 1\mid X_{3}= 0)$.
5. Find $E[X_3 \mid X_0 = 1]$ and $Var(X_3 \mid X_0 = 1).$

I need help to solve to solve part 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 1. you have calculated the matrix $$P^{(3)}=P^3=(p^{(3)}_{ij})_{i,j \in \Bbb X}$$ where $\Bbb X=\{0,1,2\}$. So, for $k\in \Bbb X$ you have that $$P(X_3=k\mid X_0=1)=p^{(3)}_{1k}$$ (these will be the entries of the first line of the matrix $P^{3}$). These values completely determine the pmf of the random variable $X_3 \mid X_0=1$ and the computation of $E[X_3 \mid X_0=1]$ and $Var(X_3 \mid X_0=1)$ are then standard.

---

Just to compare your result: $$P^3=P=
\begin{bmatrix}
193/432 & 529/1728 & 427/1728\\ 
\dots & \dots &\dots\\ 
\dots &\dots  & \dots
\end{bmatrix}$$ Hence $$E[X_3\mid X_0=1]=0\cdot\frac{193}{432}+1\cdot\frac{529}{1728}+2\frac{427}{1728}$$ and $$Var(X_3\mid X_0=1)=E[X_3^2\mid X_0=1]+\left(E[X_3\mid X_0=1]\right)^2$$ with $$E[X_3^2\mid X_0=1]=0^2\cdot\frac{193}{432}+1^2\cdot\frac{529}{1728}+2^2\frac{427}{1728}$$Can you finish the calculations?

Comment: i think i wrote the matrix incorrectly im sorry let me fix it

Comment: @Mathkid113 Ok, no problem, see my edit.

Comment: I found the probabilities same thanks a lot

Comment: @Mathkid113 So, you can upvote an answer to show that it helped you or you can accept/upvote an answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

For a)

we just calculate $P^{3}$

For b)

$ P[X_{0}=1,X_{3}=0]=P[X_{3}=0|X_{0}=1]*P[X_{0}=1]=P^{3}_{01}*P_{1}=$
$P[X_{0}=1|X_{3}=0]*P[X_{3}=0] $

For c)

we multiple [ 1/3 1/3 1/3 ] by $P^{3}$ the first elements gives us $P[X_{3}=0]$

For d)

since we know $ P[X_{0}=1,X_{3}=0]=P[X_{3}=0|X_{0}=1]*P[X_{0}=1]=P^{3}_{01}*P_{1}=$
$P[X_{0}=1|X_{3}=0]*P[X_{3}=0] $ we can just dive $P[X_{0}=1,X_{3}=0]$ by $P[X_{3}=0]$

I don't know how to solve part e) I need help